# Cannot access views from separate folder's controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

*Please view image for folder structure.*
*Note: I already tried 4 different routing option*

**Dashboard.cs**

```
public class Dashboard : Controller
        {
            public IActionResult Index()
            {
                return View("/Index");
            }
        }
```

**Startup.cs**

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

```
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Dashboard}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

Comment: You want to return the view which is in different folder other than `Views/Dashboard`? Are you seeing any error? Can you also share the folder structure inside controllers and views folder?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, I've shared an image file of folder structure. It shows the page is not found error

Comment: The image is somehow not visible in the question....

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9SE7.png

Comment: While I suggest to follow the standard folder structure for organizing views for controllers, for your specific problem you can try `return("../Index");`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, Standard folder structure ?? can you tell me more about it. And it's still not working "InvalidOperationException: The view '../Index' was not found."

Comment: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/mvc-folder-structure

Comment: https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/asp-dot-net-mvc-folder-structure/

Comment: Just using `return View("Admin/Views/Index.cshtml");`.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, Thank u for the idea. As you can see I've similar folder structure except I want separate folder for admin parts that's why

Comment: @Rena, Thank You so much it worked. Can you tell me what really happened here

Comment: Because the asp.net core would find the Views/Dashbord/Index.cshtml by default.If you do not located this razor view with the default principle,you need specify the entire razor view location.

Comment: If you do not specify the cshtml.It would still find the view from `/Views/Dashboard/Admin/Views/Index.cshtml` or `/Views/Shared/Admin/Views/Index.cshtml`.But when you specify it.It would not find from the default folder.

Comment: @Rana, Thank u so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cannot access views from separate folder's controller

The asp.net core would find the `Views/Dashbord/Index.cshtml` by default.If you do not located this razor view with the default principle,you need specify the entire razor view location.

To fix such issue,change the code like below:

```
return View("Admin/Views/Index.cshtml");
```

Comment: Thank U. Can you tell me the difference between these two lines 1. return View("Admin/Views/Index.cshtml"); 2. return View("Admin/Views/Index");

Comment: Check this documents:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.1